# Data Studio Service Account Credentials not Working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, service-accounts

I am trying to setup a Service Account for the credentials of a BigQuery data source in Data Studio (now looker studio). I have followed the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10835295?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cuse-cloud-console).

Everything is set up but when i want to add the service account to the credentials of the data source i get the following error: `This service account can't access the underlying data set.`

I am using a custom query which only access one data set as data source.

I made sure that the service account has `Big Query Data Viewer` access to he data set accessed in the query and to go even further i gave it access `Big Query Data Viewer` at the project level. I have also waited over 30 minutes but the problem is still there.

Comment: Did you grant the role BigQuery job user on the service account also? On the host project?

Comment: I did. It turned out the issue was something else.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the access, the data viewer access only allows the account to view the data and not run jobs. Given that you are using a custom query I recommend you try the `BigQuery Job User` access, [Descrption](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser). This allows the service account to run the custom query.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i had everything set up as explained in the documentation.

The problem was that within my Data Set one of the tables i was accessing in the query was **an external table stored in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage**. The service account did not have read permission on that bucket.

I **grant it read permissions to the Storage Bucket** and it finally worked.